# How to find the corresponding APR to a given APY?

Tags: interest-rate

Suppose that ​$6000 is invested in a 3​-month CD with an APY of 1.5​%

I want to find the corresponding APR to a given APY. If 6000$ is invested in a 3​ month CD with an APY of 1.5​% then according to my calculations, the corresponding APR is 1.491%

I used this relation between APY and APR to get this result: $$APY=(1+ \frac{APR}{n})^{n} -1$$
Where $n$ denotes the $n$ compounding periods per year, I'm not sure what value $n$ should take, but in my case, I guessed that $n=4$ (based on the 3 months CD). So according to this formula by writing the APY in decimal point I got the result that the APR is 1.491% but I'm not really sure if that's tru.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the CD is not relevant. The point of APR and APY numbers is that they annualize the rate you pay over a time frame that may be smaller or larger than a year. What matters is the compounding *frequency*. CDs generally compound on either a daily or monthly basis, so n will be 12 or 365, depending on the CD.

Is this a real-life problem or an homework/practice question? If it's the latter, you should probably assume n=12 because teachers seldom want you to mess with daily compounding without also telling you how many days you should assume there are in a year for compounding purposes.